# Item not deleted from array session

Tags: php, session

I have a simple PHP code that should delete a given key ($item - and passing) from an array. 
The session is there, the item as well, but on every attempt the whole session gets cleared.

```
$_SESSION['myFavorites'] = array();

if (in_array("$item", $_SESSION['myFavorites'])) { 
    unset($_SESSION['myFavorites'][$item]); 
}
```

Any help would probably set my mind straight again. Hope someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: You are looking for a *value* equal to `$item` with `in_array`, but then you are unsetting the *key* `$item`. What gives?

Comment: Are you setting `session_start()`

Comment: are you using `session_write_close()` at the end of your script? And how can there be anything withing `$_SESSION['myFavourites']`, since you set it to an empty array?

Comment: Have you tried $item instead of "$item" ?

Comment: $_SESSION['myFavorites'] = array() make it an empty array...

Answer (score 1):

```
$_SESSION['myFavorites'] = array();

if (array_key_exists($item, $_SESSION['myFavorites'])) { 
    unset($_SESSION['myFavorites'][$item]); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks you so much, Mark! Solved the problem in a second!

Comment: @Mark Parnell -  I was too late :-)